# Can we assume testing Facebook Web InstantGame will cover testing Facebook APP InstantGame as well?

Tags: facebook, selenium, testing, automated-tests

We have an Instant Game for Facebook and we would like to test it on both Web and Mobile. We had already completed automation-testing it on Web with Selenium. Now before going deeper, we wonder if Web testing covers mobile as well. Since Facebook Instant Game platform is basically an iFrame that loads our code, we wonder if it differs. Does anybody have experience on testing FB Instant Games?

Answer (score 0):

The platform (browser) is different, so no, not the same.  Events are also different.  (ex: Most phones don't generate hover...)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We tried to code some Appium tests and figured out that it loads the iFrame just as in web browser, same classnames, structure and everything. Of course some events won't be present at mobile, but can we assume for the simple cases such as "check if images are there at the iframe" that they are covered when we just do web-browser automation tests?

Comment: you know what they say about the word "assume"...  in my opinion you should always do real-world testing on all platforms you want to support.  If you spend enough time doing real-world manual testing and find no bugs that are platform specific you might have a little more confidence...